# netstat (/proc/net): why is user associated with socket root? how to get user-id of 'remote' process?

Tags: networking, users, proc, socket, netstat

ubuntu 16.04

I have 2 node applications, app-1 and app-2, with usernames matching their application names, listening locally (on ports 8001 and 8002, respectively) on the same instance. When app-1 makes a request to app-2 I can find the remoteHost of the socket handling the request from app-2. Then when I try to look up this remoteHost via netstat and retrieve some user/process information, I find that the user associated with the socket is `uid: 0` or `root`. My expectation is that the user associated with this connection would be `app-1`, since that is the application where the request is being generated. So part 1 of my question is: why is the user `root` and not `app-1`?

Part 2: My goal is to get the user id of the remote process based solely on the information in `remoteHost` (e.g. 127.0.0.1:53900). Seems to me like the operating system should know exactly what process/user-id is using that host/port combination. So, assuming `netstat` will not work, for the reasons mentioned in the previous paragraph, what other system calls or utilities could I look at to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly, I think the problem in part 1 is that I was only examining the connection after it had already been closed on 1 side (the state was `time-wait`). As a test I changed the connection type to keep-alive and now the user information appears as expected.

The answer for part 2 will then be reading the same files as `netstat` (/proc/net/*) and searching for the `remoteHost`.